# Changing permalink structure and domain

Tags: permalinks, domain

Who could help me with the following:

I am moving my site to another domain AND I want to change my permalink structure. I wish to edit my .htaccess file of my OLD domain.

So:

http://www.olddomain.com/%YEAR/%MONTH/%DATE/example-post

SHOULD BE 301 REDIRECTED TO

http://www.newdomain.com/example-post

All my old URL's should be 301 redirected to the new URL's and new permalink structure.

What are the necessary steps I should take?

Comment: this blog post may can be your solution https://techtage.com/changing-permalink-structure-wordpress/

Comment: thanks, but this generator only works with changing permalink structure and in my case I am changing domains too.

Comment: you can try to add additional php redirect on your single.php template. So after the oldmain get redirected with .htaccess rule you can redirect using php into newdomain

Comment: I only want to edit my .htaccess file on my old domain

Comment: please check my aswer @Rick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on your **old domain**  add this following rule at the top of .htaccess

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/$3
```

plase let me know if its work or not.

Comment: you can mark my answer as accepted.. so people with the same problem  will know the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Mod_Rewrite is active, on .htaccess file you can use:

Redirect 301 http://www.olddomain.com/2015/05/22/example-post  http://www.newdomain.com/example-post

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear. It concerns ALL links on the old site. Not just one URL.